# Amazon RDS - Can't access MySQL DB from local machine

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I read many questions/answers here but they are from a different interface from AWS Console. I created a DB Instance but can't create a rule in the security groups that's allows me to connect from my computer. I tried these rules :

- All tcp with my IP
- All traffic with my IP
- MySQL with my IP

By the way I'm using MySQL Query Browser

Anyone knows the right rule to use ?

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help

Comment: Any of those three rules would allow you to access the database, so I suspect that either those rules were set on the wrong security group or that you are trying to connect to the wrong hostname. Anonymize the hostname but leave the basic format intact so that we can see to what host you are trying to connect. Also, mention the name of the security group that you are adding the rule to. At a minimum, I can show you how to tunnel your connection through an EC2 instance if need be.